# Using XPATH in jmeter - based on parent

Tags: jmeter

I have a xml file having the following structure:

```
           <subscriberDetailsItem>
                <externalSubId>911</externalSubId>
                <paymentIndicator>2</paymentIndicator>
                <IMSI>302</IMSI>
                <MSISDN>416</MSISDN>
                <status>A</status>
                <outSubscriptionDetails>
                    <subscriptionDetailsItem>
                        <socId>ABCDEF</socId>
                        <featureCode>GHIJKL</featureCode>
                        <startDate>20180720000000</startDate>
                        <featureSeq>47452111</featureSeq>
                        <subscriptionType>DATA</subscriptionType>
                        <shareGroupCd>SHARE</shareGroupCd>
                        <initialValueBytes>1073741824</initialValueBytes>
                        <priority>3000</priority>
                        <balanceType>BAL</balanceType>
                    </subscriptionDetailsItem>
                </outSubscriptionDetails>
            </subscriberDetailsItem>
```

I want to be able to extract the `socID` field based on the `externalSubId`  field. Essentially, I want to be able to do this:

if `externalSubId=911`, then, extract `SOCID`. Anyone has tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify *where* would you want to extract it, so I assume you can use **XPath Extractor** as a post-processor to some sampler that reads that file.

You configure post-processor like this:

[image]

XPath Query can be built like this:

1. Select `subscriberDetailsItem` that has `externalSubId` with the value you want:

   ```
   //subscriberDetailsItem[externalSubId=911]
   ```
2. Select `socId` either by using absolute path:

   ```
   //subscriberDetailsItem[externalSubId=911]/outSubscriptionDetails/subscriptionDetailsItem/socId
   ```

   or you can omit entities in the middle if `socId` cannot be found elsewhere in the item:

   ```
   //subscriberDetailsItem[externalSubId=911]//socId
   ```